# Keeping font within a float left div to stay on left margin

Tags: html, css, .net

I have three divs that are all float left. Like so: (1)(2)(3). Now, if the spans font within div1 is longer then the width I set, it goes to next line in the div. This is fine, but the next line is no longer at the left most margin of the div. It looks like the inside text of the div when longer then one line is set to center, not margin left. How can I go about handling this. The current css I have is here:

```
.left-div-results-list  div:first-child{ 
    width:70%;       
    float:left;
}
.left-div-results-list div:nth-child(2){
    float:left;
    width:10%;        
}
.left-div-results-list div:nth-child(2){
    width:10%;
    float:left;
}
.left-div-results-list tr td{
    min-width:400px;
}
```

here is an example:

```
> -------------------------------
> -   this is correct
> -
> -
> -
> -
> --------------------------------
> 
> --------------------------------
> -
> - this is not correct when the
> -     length is longer.   --> This needs to also be left aligned.!
> -
> --------------------------------
```

Comment: Wait, this is totally a dumb question, and over looked something. text-align. lol

Comment: try text-align:left; in your div results

Comment: Yea, that is what I overlooked and then posted response above your mentioning of it.  lol, I don't know why i asked the question, and didn't think of the text-align.

Answer (score 0):

I over looked the obvious answer, and as long as the properties are not being over written, text-align left was the cause.